# WPF MediaElement video won't play after being hidden in storyboard

Tags: wpf, expression-blend

I'll start of by describing the problem, and then follow up with details about the process I'm going though.

**Problem:**

I'm having an issue where I'm playing a MediaElement on one storyboard and then setting the same MediaElement to hidden in another.  After having the MediaElement set to hidden, I'm unable to replay the video portion of that storyboard again (non-MediaElement animations still happen.) Videos are WMVs encoded in VC-1 at 10,000 Kbps at a resolution of 1560x1004 and provided alongside the project as relative assets.

**Details:**

I'm working on a Kiosk application which makes use of a large number of videos combined with some graphical effects for real-time animation.  Presently I'm creating storyboards using Blend, layering the videos for playback in the desired sequence.  Below details two sample storyboard from the page:

[image: Open Storyboard]
Open performs the following:

1. Set's meOpen's visibility to 100%, Visible
2. Set's meIn's visibility to Hidden at 1 second (masking the start of meOpen)
3. Starts playing meOpen at 0:00.900.

[image]

Before playing the Close storyboard the Open storyboard is played, and the system waits for user input to continue.  Once Close is triggered, the following happens:

1. meOpen  - A MediaElement that has it's visibility set to 'Hidden' at 1 second
2. meClose - A MediaElement that is the desired video to play.  I have it starting slightly before meOpen is hidden to mask the first frame 'black frame' while the element is loading the video
3. The rest of the items is just fading visibility of overlay elements.

The storyboard works for running through the video; however, if I try and play the Open storyboard a second time, meOpen does not play.

Thanks

Comment: I think you first have to set the value of the MediaElements Visiility back to Visible before the animation plays another time.

Comment: That would also be my understanding.  I've tried explicitly setting visibility on Open at both first frame and on media play; however, neither seems to affect the playback.

Comment: I had the exactly same problem and the solution which worked for me was to set the values back by animation. Im sure there are some other solutions but maybe you wanna try this.

Comment: How would I reset the visibility from animation?  I've tried setting a key frame in the storyboard as well as setting visibility on close's storyboard completion (and video media ended) methods; none of which work.

Comment: Thanks Florian Gl,

For some reason setting the visibility from within Blend wasn't cutting it; however, took your suggestion and added a animation from within XAML and that seems to have done the trick.

Comment: Edit: 

For anyone wondering.  Setting a key frame from within Blend only applies values changed from the current state.  In this case the media elements were defaulted to visible, so attempting to set a key frame on storyboard start would not apply the animation value for the media element.  

This was resolved by setting the default state of the media elements to hidden, and setting a key frame with the desired visibility from within the storyboard.